# can't mount partition - how can I troubleshoot it?

Tags: linux, filesystems, sd-card

I have an SD card which was used in Raspberry Pi. I want to mount this SD card on a Linux PC to get files from it, but I can't.

When I put the SD card in a card reader, my dmesg says:

```
  [  114.117896] usb 4-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using ohci-pci
  [  114.292885] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=214b, idProduct=1101
  [  114.292897] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
  [  114.292904] usb 4-1: Product: USB2.0 Device   
  [  114.292910] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Generic 
  [  114.292914] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 0201202010201000
  [  114.383603] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
  [  114.383803] scsi6 : usb-storage 4-1:1.0
  [  114.383956] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
  [  115.386965] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB2.0   CARD-READER      1.01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
  [  115.388961] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
  [  115.409892] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
  [  115.471798] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 30679040 512-byte logical blocks: (15.7 GB/14.6 GiB)
  [  115.505782] sdc: detected capacity change from 0 to 15707668480
  [  115.534776]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 < sdc5 sdc6 > sdc3
```

The partition table of this card is:

```
  # parted /dev/sdc
  GNU Parted 3.2
  Using /dev/sdc
  Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
  (parted) print                                                            
  Model: USB2.0 CARD-READER (scsi)
  Disk /dev/sdc: 15,7GB
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
  Partition Table: msdos
  Disk Flags: 

  Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
   1      1049kB  1275MB  1274MB  primary   fat32        lba
   2      1278MB  15,7GB  14,4GB  extended
   5      1279MB  1342MB  62,9MB  logical   fat16        lba
   6      1343MB  15,7GB  14,3GB  logical
   3      15,7GB  15,7GB  33,6MB  primary
```

When I check this device with fdisk, it says:

```
  # fdisk /dev/sdc -l

  Disk /dev/sdc: 14.6 GiB, 15707668480 bytes, 30679040 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disklabel type: dos
  Disk identifier: 0x000daf86

  Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
  /dev/sdc1           2048  2490234  2488187  1.2G  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
  /dev/sdc2        2496512 30609407 28112896 13.4G 85 Linux extended
  /dev/sdc3       30613504 30679039    65536   32M 83 Linux
  /dev/sdc5        2498560  2621439   122880   60M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
  /dev/sdc6        2623488 30607359 27983872 13.4G 83 Linux
  Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

It seems that /dev/sdc6 is the biggest partition, so I want to mount it. When I try to mount it, I get this result:

```
  # mount -v /dev/sdc6 test
  mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc6,
         missing codepage or helper program, or other error

         In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
         dmesg | tail or so.
```

Dmesg doesn't say anything when I try to mount /dev/sdc6.

When I check this partition with *file* command, it says:

```
    # file -s /dev/sdc6
    /dev/sdc6: data
```

When I check the filesystem with fsck, I get:

```
  # LC_ALL=C fsck.ext3 -n /dev/sdc6
  e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
  ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
  fsck.ext3: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
  root was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
  Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
  Pass 2: Checking directory structure
  Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
  Pass 4: Checking reference counts
  Pass 5: Checking group summary information
  Free blocks count wrong for group #0 (4245, counted=11608).
  Fix? no

  Free blocks count wrong for group #1 (1373, counted=707).
  Fix? no

  Free blocks count wrong for group #2 (1699, counted=1880).
  Fix? no

  (...)

  Inode bitmap differences:  -(57345--131072) -172034 -172037 -(172042--172043) -172045 -172047 -172049 -172053 -172057 -172059 -172062 -172065 (...)
  Fix? no

  root: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

  root: 91692/876544 files (0.8% non-contiguous), 1413337/3497984 blocks
```

I understand that due to some unknown reason Linux can't mount this filesystem. I would like to know why - is filesystem broken, or is there some other reason? And I would like either to mount this filesystem or somehow recover its files.

What should I do now to troubleshoot this problem?

EDIT: I want to thank everybody for help! Finally I found - using fsck - that the partition does contain Linux ext filesystem, but the filesystem is broken and this is why I could not mount it. I did a backup of the card (with "cat /dev/sdc | gzip > mybackup") and then checked if the device contains bad blocks. It does not contain any bad blocks (maybe the filesystem on the SD card was broken by usind it with a broken SD card reader?), so I just fixed the filesystem with fsck, put the card in the Raspberry Pi and then it booted without problems.

Comment: Are you running that on the Raspberry or on another Linux PC ?

Comment: I run it on another Linux PC.

Comment: That should go into the question

Comment: Done - I added an information that I want to mount it on a Linux PC.

Comment: What is the output of `fsck.ext3 -n /dev/sdc6`? The `-n` option means that no changes will be made.

Comment: Can you boot the card from your Pi and look to see what it's expecting? That would be much safer - and more reliable - than trying to guess from the outside.

Comment: VPfB: I added the output of fsck.

Comment: roaima: I will be able to boot the card from my Pi on Tuesday - until then I try to troubleshoot it using other ways.

Answer (score 3):

According to the posted `fsck` output, there is hope that some data might be recovered.

I would recommend:

1. make a `dd` copy of the filesystem to a disk file (e.g. `fdsump.orig`). If it fails, try `ddrescue`. Make sure you have enough free space before you begin.
2. Do not work directly on this file, but create a new copy (e.g. `cp fsdump.orig fsdump`), so you can always return to this step and start again.
3. with `mount -o loop` create a device from the `fsdump` data file (e.g. `/dev/loop1`)
4. try `fsck.ext3 /dev/loop1` until there will be no errors. The more passes will be needed, the bigger is the damage.
5. mount the `/dev/loop1` to a directory. Copy all files to a  safe location. (Use `cp -a` or `rsync` to preserve file attributes). Any of them may be corrupted, truncated, etc.
6. You may now umount the loop filesystem.

---

See man pages of the mentioned utilities for details.

Answer (score 2):

You might use [file(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) as `file -s /dev/sdc6` this would read some bytes from the block device and guess what is there.

If nothing is recognized, you are in trouble and you might have lost your data; to do anything to recover it, you should know *a priori* what file system was there.

If some file system is recognized, you could try to use [mount(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) with an explicit `-t` *`type`*

> Partition table entries are not in disk order

This smells not very good. Perhaps you'll need to repartition entirely your disk  (but backup its data before); it looks that you have two partitions overlapping (`sdc2` and `sdc6`)

Since you are running on some other Linux PC, you could copy the data from the SD card to the PC (into some file), perhaps using [dd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html)

```
dd if=/dev/sdc6 of=$HOME/diskdata bs=4k
```

BTW, do check with `dmesg` after that command that the copy went well.

You could even copy with `dd` the entire SD card.

Then you might spend hours (or months) of work to try to decipher the mess in that `$HOME/diskdata` file on your Linux PC. You could use [debugfs(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/debugfs.8.html) for that purpose, if you believe the original file system was ext3 or ext4

SD cards are fragile devices and they wear out quickly. I guess yours is physically broken. Prepare yourself to some definitive data loss.

Comment: I added the output of "file -s /dev/sdc6" to the question body.